# My private binary tree int list is giving me the wrong output, how do I fix it?

Tags: java, data-structures

The outputs are all pretty different so that causes me some trouble trying to fix it.

Here is one: (0 stops the list from populating)

```
run:
Enter an integer to be inserted or 0 to quit:
1
2
3
0
"printing P:"
1
2
3
"now copying:"
1
"done printing Q"
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

Here is another:

```
run:
Enter an integer to be inserted or 0 to quit:
1
2
3
-4
-5
-6
0
printing P
-6
-5
-4
1
2
3
now copying
-6
-5
-4
1
done printing Q
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
```

One more, which works:

```
run:
Enter an integer to be inserted or 0 to quit:
6
5
4
0
printing P
4
5
6
now copying
4
5
6
done printing Q
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)
```

So it only copies the lowest number entered, unless there are negative numbers, in which case it copies those but only the lowest positive number entered. The negative numbers work fine, it's only the positive numbers entered in ascending order that don't copy.

Here is the class:

```
public class Intcoll6
  {
    private int howmany;
private btNode c;

public Intcoll6()
  {
    howmany = 0;
    c = null;
  }
//we have to use this private class
private class btNode
  {
    int info;
    btNode left;
    btNode right;

    public btNode()
      {
        info = 0;
        left = null;
        right = null;
      }
  }
public boolean belongs(int i)
  {
    boolean result = false;
    btNode p = c;
    while ((p != null) && (p.info != i))
      {
        if (i < p.info)
          {
            p = p.left;
          }
        if (p.info > i)
          {
            p = p.right;
          }
        if (p != null)
          {
            result = true;
          }
      }
    return result;
  }
//I believe the problem is with this method
public void insert(int i)
  {
    btNode p = c;
    btNode pred = null;
    while ((p != null) && (p.info != i))
      {
        pred = p;
        if (i < p.info)
          {
            p = p.left;
          } else if (i > p.info)
          {
            p = p.right;
          }
      }
    if (p == null)
      {
        howmany = howmany + 1;
        p = new btNode();
        if (pred != null)
          {
            if (i < pred.info)
              {
                pred.left = p;
              }
            if (i > pred.info)
              {
                pred.right = p;
              }
            p.info = i;
          }
        if (pred == null)
          {
            c = p;
            p.info = i;
          }

      }
  }

public void omit(int i)
  {
    btNode p = c;
    btNode pred = null;
    while ((p != null) && (p.info != i))
      {
        pred = p;
        if (i < p.info)
          {
            p = p.left;
          }
        if (i > p.info)
          {
            p = p.right;
          }
      }
    if (p != null)
      {
        howmany--;
        if (pred != null)
          {
            if ((p.left == null) && (p.right == null))
              {
                if (p.info > pred.info)
                  {
                    pred.right = null;
                  } else
                  {
                    pred.left = null;
                  }
              } else if ((p.left != null) && (p.right == null))
              {
                if (p.info > pred.info)
                  {
                    pred.right = p.left;
                  } else
                  {
                    pred.left = p.left;
                  }
              } else if ((p.right != null) && (p.left == null))
              {
                if (p.info < pred.info)
                  {
                    pred.left = p.right;
                  } else
                  {
                    pred.right = p.right;
                  }
              } else if ((p.left != null) && (p.right != null))
              {
                if (p.info > pred.info)
                  {
                    btNode q = p;
                    btNode q1 = pred;
                    while (q != null)
                      {
                        q1 = q;
                        q = q.left;
                      }
                    p.info = q.info;
                    q1.left = null;

                  }
                if (p.info < pred.info)
                  {
                    btNode q = p;
                    btNode q1 = p;
                    while (q != null)
                      {
                        q1 = q;
                        q = q.right;
                      }
                    p.info = q.info;
                    q1.right = null;
                  }
              }
          }
        if (pred == null)
          {
            if ((p.left == null) && (p.right == null))
              {
                c = null;
              } else if ((p.left != null) && (p.right == null))
              {
                c = p.left;
              } else if ((p.left == null) && (p.right != null))
              {
                c = p.right;
              } else if ((p.right != null) && (p.left != null))
              {
                btNode q = p;
                btNode q1 = pred;
                while (q != null)
                  {
                    q1 = q;
                    q = q.right;
                  }
                p.info = q.info;
                q1.right = null;

              }
          }
      }
  }
private btNode copyTree(btNode tree)
{
    btNode result = null;
    if(tree != null)
    {
        btNode L;
        btNode R;
        L = copyTree(tree.left);
        R = copyTree(tree.right);
        result = new btNode();
        result.info = tree.info;
        result.left = L;
        tree.right = R;
    }
    return result;
}  
public void copy (Intcoll6 obj)
{
    if(this != obj)
    {
    howmany = obj.howmany;
    c = copyTree(obj.c);
    }
}
private static void printtree(btNode t)
  {
    if (t != null)
      {
        printtree(t.left);
        System.out.println(t.info);
        printtree(t.right);
      }
  }
public void print()
  {
    printtree(c);
  }
public boolean equals(Intcoll6 obj)
  {
    boolean result = (howmany == obj.howmany);
    btNode p = c;
    btNode q = obj.c;
    while ((p != null) && (q != null))
      {
        btNode pred = p;
        if ((p.info == q.info))
          {
            if (p.info >= pred.info)
              {
                p = p.right;
                q = q.right;
              }
          }
        if ((p == null) && (q == null))
          {
            result = true;
          }
      }
    return result;
  }  
  }
```

Driver:

```
import intcoll6.Intcoll6;
import java.util.*;
import static intcoll6.Intcoll6Client.SENTINEL;
public class Driver6
  {
int value;
public static final int SENTINEL = 0;
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("Enter an integer to be inserted or 0 to quit:");
    int value;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    value = keyboard.nextInt();
    Intcoll6 P = new Intcoll6();
    while (value != SENTINEL)
      {
        P.insert(value);
        value = keyboard.nextInt();
      }
    System.out.println("printing P");
    P.print();
    System.out.println("now copying");
    Intcoll6 Q = new Intcoll6();
    Q.copy(P);
    Q.print();
    System.out.println("done printing Q");
  }
  }
```

Here is the correct copyTree method:

```
private btNode copyTree(btNode tree)
      {
    btNode test = null;
    if (tree != null)
      {
        test = new btNode();
        test.info = tree.info;
        test.left = copyTree (tree.left);
        test.right = copyTree(tree.right);
      }
    return test;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger, or some log statements, to see what is going on? It would be more educational for you to solve this yourself. In a programming job you can't always ask your colleagues to find your bugs for you.

Comment: I'm having trouble because I tried the debugger and maybe because it is a private class tree, it doesn't give me the values of each node in the tree, just the most recent int so I can't really see what is going on.

I know I can't ask my colleagues in a job, I'm just stuck (have been trying for days). If someone could even tell me where the problem is but not necessarily how to fix it that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Well, this is a perfectly good time to learn about debugging.  Also a good time to learn how to write comments.

Comment: Yes, I often find a traditional debugger frustrating because it only shows the current value of a variable that I am looking at (although it is possible to "drill down" into data structures). That's why I often use log statements, or System.out.printlns. There is another option that you may find useful: http://chrononsystems.com/ - they have a free trial version.

Comment: Hot Licks, how would you go about debugging this? I use the debugger and it doesn't tell me the values being passed. Just says # with some numbers that I don't understand how they relate, as they are much higher. I enter 1,2,3 it says something like #189 or something to that effect. Is there a way that I can see the other vars and not just the current one?

Comment: Here is the correct copyTree method:

    private btNode copyTree(btNode tree)
      {
        btNode test = null;
        if (tree != null)
          {
            test = new btNode();
            test.info = tree.info;
            test.left = copyTree (tree.left);
            test.right = copyTree(tree.right);
          }
        return test;
      }

Answer (score 0):

You never set the right tree properly in your copy statement.
Saying tree.right = R is assigning the copy of the right tree to the parameter that was sent to the method.
 You should be copying the tree to the local variable **result**.

Everything to the right of the tree is missing after you've exited this method and so it never prints the rest because it only knows about the left side of the tree.

```
private btNode copyTree(btNode tree)
{
    btNode result = null;
    if(tree != null)
    {
        btNode L;
        btNode R;
        L = copyTree(tree.left);
        R = copyTree(tree.right);
        result = new btNode();
        result.info = tree.info;
        result.left = L;
        //wrong//--> tree.right = R;
        //Should be// -- > result.right = R;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It only copies the lowest numbers because in a tree the lower numbers go on the left and you're only copying the left side of the tree. If you said 4 5 6 instead of 6 5 4, you would most likely only get 4